# How do you refer to a type from an existing type?

Tags: typescript

In React-native is a component `FlatList` which has a property `ListHeaderComponent` how do I specify the type it is using without copying and pasting the original type.

Right now I have

```
export function AccountMediaGalleryComponent({
  style,
  ListHeaderComponent,
  ListHeaderComponentStyle,
}: {
  style: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  ListHeaderComponent?: React.ComponentType<any> | React.ReactElement | null;
  ListHeaderComponentStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
}): JSX.Element {
```

I was hoping for something like

```
ListHeaderComponent?: typeof FlatList.ListHeaderComponent
```

But that does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in react-native, but I *think* if you have a value of type `ListComponent`, then it has a property named `props` which itself has a property named `ListHeaderComponent`, and it is this property type you're looking for.

If so, you can use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the type you want.  You can think of it as "lifting" the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) for property accesses to the type level; if a value `t` has type `T`, and a value `k` has type `K`, then the value `t[k]` has type `T[K]`.  (You can't use dot notation for this, primarily because such notation would cause ambiguity in the type system; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30815](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30815) for more information).

So, if you had a value of type `FlatList`, indexed into it with a value of [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type `"props"`, and indexed into *that* with a value of literal type `"ListHeaderComponent"`, you would get a value of this type:

```
type ListHeaderComponent = FlatList["props"]["ListHeaderComponent"];
```

which evaluates to what I think you're looking for:

```
/* type ListHeaderComponent = 
     React.ComponentType<any> | 
     React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> |
     null | undefined */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMQDYEMYBlgGd4C+cAZlBCHAORQCm6AxjALQB2mwAbjZQLABQ-GAE8wNODnwAJOgBMaUAMLlILGi3gBeFBmx4YAbQBEYMmFyGAukYkxp6OYuURV6ywG5+-APQAqOMNFxPTsHJXBnNU04fjhYgCU6RgA6MJVIgBURGgAedBYhAD44AB84BIYYJPLGAFFUGhBI3PyAGjh8KGAWAHMSssTKgCkAZQANOobIpRYOgFdGaGbCotKY2JZZ1FQ+2ZY5Yi6aGTgfL08+Lph5YgYxZAgIRDXYmxD5VIj1AH4ALiCpWTvJwuGD8AjnIA)